# Swap two JLabels based on clicks

Tags: jpanel, jlabel, swap

How can I use this code to click on one JLabel in a JPanel and then click again on another JLabel in a seperate panel and have the two JLabels swap? I am creating a grid of panels with each one containing a JLabel wsith an image Icon. I would like to click on an Icon and then click on another panel and have the contents swap. What am I doing wrong?

```
package testcomponentat;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestComponentAt extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 8;
   private static final int W = 60;
   private static final int H = W;
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(W, H);
   protected static final Color SELECTION_COLOR = Color.pink;
   private JPanel selectedPanel = null;
   private Color originalColor = null;
   private static int r, c = 0;
   private static final ImageIcon im1 = new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");
   private static final ImageIcon im2 = new ImageIcon("image2.jpg");
   private static boolean swap = false;
   private static JPanel panel1, panel2;

   public TestComponentAt() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
      setBackground(Color.black);

      for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT * ROW_COUNT; i++) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel();
        String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", i / ROW_COUNT, i % ROW_COUNT);
        panel.setName(name);
        if (i == 0) {
           originalColor = panel.getBackground();
        }

        r = i % ROW_COUNT;
        c = i  % ROW_COUNT;

        if(c == 1){ jlab.setIcon(im1); }
        if(c == 6){ jlab.setIcon(im2); }

        panel.add(jlab);
        panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
        add(panel);
      }

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(swap == false){
                 panel1 = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                 //panel1 = (JPanel) e.getComponent();
                if (panel1 == null || panel1 == TestComponentAt.this) {
                   return;
                }
                if (selectedPanel != null) {
                   selectedPanel.setBackground(originalColor);
                   //selectedPanel.removeAll();
                   selectedPanel.revalidate();
                   selectedPanel.repaint();
                }
                selectedPanel = panel1;
                selectedPanel.setBackground(SELECTION_COLOR);
                selectedPanel.add(new JLabel(selectedPanel.getName()));
                selectedPanel.revalidate();
                selectedPanel.repaint();
                swap = true;
            }
            else{
                JPanel temp = new JPanel();
                panel2 = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                if (panel2 == null || panel2 == TestComponentAt.this) {
                   return;
                }
                if (selectedPanel != null) {
                   selectedPanel.setBackground(originalColor);
                   //selectedPanel.removeAll();
                   selectedPanel.revalidate();
                   selectedPanel.repaint();
                 }
                selectedPanel = panel2;
                selectedPanel.setBackground(SELECTION_COLOR);
                selectedPanel.add(new JLabel(selectedPanel.getName()));
                temp = panel1;
                panel1 = panel2;
                panel2 = panel1;
                selectedPanel.revalidate();
                selectedPanel.repaint();
                swap = false; 
            }
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestComponentAt");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestComponentAt());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my own code to try and figure out what you were trying to do... here is what I came up with I hope it helps... though I JUST noticed this was posted a month ago...

Java file name "SplashScreen.java":

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {

JPanel[] p1 = new JPanel[9];
JPanel mainP = new JPanel();
JLabel[] l1 = new JLabel[9];
boolean[] l1Clicked = new boolean[9];
boolean bufferFull = false;
String temp;

public SplashScreen() {
    createSplash();
}

public void createSplash() {
    mainP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mouseHandler mh = new mouseHandler();
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) {
        l1[i] = new JLabel("" + i);
        p1[i] = new JPanel();
        p1[i].add(l1[i]);
        p1[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        p1[i].addMouseListener(mh);
        l1Clicked[i] = false;
        mainP.add(p1[i]);
    }
    add(mainP);
    //add(p2);
}

public class mouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == p1[0]) {
            if (bufferFull == false) {
                temp = l1[0].getText();
                bufferFull = true;
                l1Clicked[0] = true;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < l1Clicked.length; i++) {
                    if (l1Clicked[i] == true) {
                        l1[i].setText(l1[0].getText());
                        l1Clicked[i] = false; 
                        bufferFull = false;
                    }

                }
                l1[0].setText(temp);

            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == p1[1]) {
            if (bufferFull == false) {
                temp = l1[1].getText();
                bufferFull = true;
                l1Clicked[1] = true;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < l1Clicked.length; i++) {
                    if (l1Clicked[i] == true) {
                        l1[i].setText(l1[1].getText());
                        l1Clicked[i] = false;
                        bufferFull = false;
                    }
                }
                l1[1].setText(temp);

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("You get the point");
        }



    }
}
}
```

Java file name "ImageTest.java":

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class ImageTest extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SplashScreen ss = new SplashScreen();
    ss.setVisible(true);
    ss.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ss.setSize(500,500);
}
}
```

Works FINE! :) Simply made TWO arrays. one for the JPanels and the other for JLabels.
You add a mouse listener to each JPanel. now when the user clicks on one it will check whether or not another has been clicked before and if it hasnt it gets that Labels text and add it to a temp string. Run it and see how it goes